# Ahlfors' Complex Analysis: proof of a lemma concerning algebraic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a difficulty understanding one step in the proof of Lemma 1 on p. 302-303 in Ahlfors' Complex Analysis, 3rd edition. (This is the lemma establishing existence of algebraic function elements $(f_1,\Delta),\ldots,(f_n,\Delta)$ satisfying $P(f_i(z),z) = 0$ for $i = 1,\ldots,n$, and their basic properties).

Ahlfors' proof is based on representing each function $f_i$ as
$$f_i(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{C_i} w \frac{P_w(w,z)}{P(w,z)} dw$$
for a suitable closed curve $C_i$, where the polynomial $P(\cdot,z)$ has a single simple root in the interior of $C_i$, and no root on $C_i$.

Alhfors states as obvious that this integral representation of $f_i(z)$ implies that the function $f_i(z)$ is analytic – and this is the point I do not understand. Is there any simple argument that can be used to observe analyticity of $f_i(z)$? Any help appreciated.

Comment: The integrand is holomorphic in $z$. Two standard ways to deduce that the integral is holomorphic in $z$ are 1) showing the integral depends continuously on $z$ and applying Morera's theorem, 2) differentiating under the integral sign. How easy these are to justify depends on how much integration theory you can draw from.

Comment: I would avoid to use "i" as an index.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, both should work...

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, of course; sadly, this is Ahlfors' original notation.